# Calculate time in Excel by exact time

Tags: excel

I have a cell **A3** as 10.55 and **B3** as 20.35. Now i have to calculate the different value as time. It means i should get the value like 9 hours and 40 mins. it should print like 9.40 in the **C3**.

I have tried this but it is not give the exact value.

```
=TIME(FLOOR((B3-A3), 1), ((B3-A3) - FLOOR((B3-A3), 1)) * 100, 0)
```

Is there any other way to solve it ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the native Excel time format 10:55 and 20:35 instead, you can simply do a substraction to get your desired result.

Comment: Using the format _h.mm_ should output the difference as requested.

Comment: When i use time format an type a simple decimal number, it is converting to some other number.

Comment: Unless you have a requirement to use decimal numbers, you should use a colon instead as this enables native date and time calculations.

Answer (score 0):

A3:

```
=TIME(10;55;00)
```

B3:

```
=TIME(20;35;00)
```

C3:

```
=TEXT(B3-A3;"g.mm")
```

Should work. ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set the number format in all 3 cells as **h.mm** (Right click on cells, Format Cells..., Number tab, Custom category).

Then, when you enter the time it should be in the standard format 10:55, otherwise it will be consider as number, indeed. Why this happens: MS Excel consider all dates as numbers. The integer part are the number of days since 1900, the fractional part are the hours. The difference between number and date is only the number format as number or as date/time.

If you do like this, if simply use the formula **=B3-A3**, you will get the time difference.